# Python run commands in one instance of CMD

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I have this code:

```
import os

os.system('set x=5')
os.system('echo %x%')
```

When I do this, I expect to get `5` outputted to the screen, but instead I get `%x%`. I think this is because these two commands are being run on 2 different command prompt instances. If anyone can help, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `os.system('set x=5 && echo %x%')`?

Comment: But assuming I want to do it from 2 separate commands, what would I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems "set" command should be replace with "os.environ" method in python.
This way, you can set environment variable.

```
import os
os.environ['x'] = "5"
os.system('echo %x%')

#result is "5"
```

I think this is the easiest way to achieve your goal.
Hope this can help you:)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but as I said above, I would like to do it from 2 separate commands. The example I have given is a simplified version of what I hope to do.

Comment: @Pokechu48 thank you for your quick feedback. I changed my reply.
I think you should use "os.environ" instead of using "set" command in "os.system" method.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly recommended to do this but if you really want to programmatically interface with a console emulating the way you would do it normally you can manipulate the stdin and stdout buffers. The subprocess module has some tools for that in python.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
p.stdin.write('set x=5\n')
p.stdin.write('echo %x%\n')
print p.communicate()[0]
p.terminate()
```